# No jupyterhub access to GPU

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, python, jupyter

Platform: x86_64, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, 5.15.0-101-generic, jupyterhub 2.0.0+ds1-2

I've installed `jupyterhub` from the official Ubuntu software repositories (package `jupyterhub`). This works and I can login and run Python code. Within the jupyterhub, I'm using the same Python version as my system Python. I don't think it is an issue of having different versions of libraries installed.

From [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/), I can get GPU access from multiple users' consoles including from within IPython:

```
moo@hostname:~$ ipython3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import torch
In [2]: torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[2]: True
```

But it doesn't work within the jupyterhub:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()

False
```

It looks like this is a problem with jupyterhub permissions/access. From within jupyterhub:

```
!nvidia-smi

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

This works fine on the console from the user that I get when I run `!whoami` within jupyter.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to try next?